# Why are layout attributes of root element not inflated?

Tags: android, layout-inflater, layoutparams

I have a `RecyclerView`. I want the "cells" to take up the full width of the `RecyclerView`, but they are not.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
    val binding = MyCellBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)  
    // here, binding.root.layoutParams is null ??      
    return MyHolder(binding)
}
```

The `MyHolder` class is the usual `ViewHolder` subclass.

The `MyCellBinding` is from `layout/my_cell.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"   ← ✅
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  ← ✅
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

The `layout_width/height` on the `TextView` get created correctly, but for some reason there are no `LayoutParams` on the `binding.root` - the `LinearLayout`. So when it displays in the list it is as narrow as the `TextView`.

I can use the LayoutInspector to see that the parent of the `LinearLayout` is the `RecyclerView`.

Why are the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of the root `LinearLayout` not inflated from the XML?

Comment: match_parent means take the whole size of the parent, not the whole size of the screen.

Comment: Beyond that, try `val binding = MyCellBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)`. Always prefer the three-parameter form of `inflate()` when you know the parent.

Comment: @m0skit0 Sorry, I explained that wrong; I just edited the question to clarify. I want to match the width of the parent RecyclerView. (Which happens to be taking up the whole screen on my phone.)